# HTML Styles in TextView on Mono for Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I have this situation in my strings.xml.

```
<string name="mensagem">Olá <b><i> {0} </i></b>,</string>
```

And in my code I do this:

```
string msg = String.Format(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.mensagem).ToString(), cliente.Nome.ToUpper());
lblNome.Text = Html.FromHtml(msg).ToString();
```

But the style tags (b,i) do not work. I need to concatenate words with and without style, so I need to do it in this way. I cant use `setTypeface` because I need to style individual words and after that, join those words on a sentence.

What is the way ?

Regards,
Marcelo.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change your code to the following.

```
string msg = String.Format(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.mensagem).ToString(), cliente.Nome.ToUpper());
lblNome.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(msg);
```

`Html.FromHtml(string).ToString()` is just converting the formatted `ISpannable` back to a string so you are losing the formatting.